# T-SQL Trigger only when column value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and have the following trigger:

```
USE [gatordata]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TriggerUserAssigned] Script Date:2/20/2016 3:42:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerUserAssigned]
ON [dbo].[User]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE([AssignedToUser]) 
BEGIN
declare @Id int;
declare @AssignedToUser nvarchar(50);
declare @TimeStamp datetime;
declare @Hour bit;
declare @RushService bit;
declare @Status nvarchar(50);
select @Id=i.Id from inserted i;
select @AssignedToUser=i.AssignedToUser from inserted i;
select @Hour=i.[Hour] from inserted i;
select @RushService=i.[RushService] from inserted i;
select @Status=i.[Status] from inserted i;

INSERT INTO [Messages]  
(RequestID,AssignedToUser,[TimeStamp],[Hour],RushService,[Status],MessageText) VALUES (@Id,@AssignedToUser,GETDATE(),@Hour,@RushService,@Status,'New Critical Request')
END
```

This is working fine except I need to modify it so it only triggers the insert to the "Messages" table when the column "AssignedToUser" value actually changes to a new value.  If the value of "AssignedToUser" remains the same when the row is updated the trigger should not fire.  Thanks in advance SO friends...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you have a primary key on `Users`, this is not difficult.  Let me assume that primary key is `RequestId`.

Then:

```
insert into messages( . . . )
    select i.id, i.assignedtouser, i.hour, i.rushservice, i.status
    from inserted i join
         deleted d
         on i.requestid = d.requestid
    where i.assignedtouser <> d.assignedtouser;
```

Note:  You should *never* assume that `inserted` and `deleted` have only one row, as your original code does.  This will simply fail when someone attempts to `update` multiple rows.

You should also explicitly include the column list in an `insert` statement.  So the `. . .` is for the list of columns in the `messages` table.

Comment: Gordon thanks so much for the quick response and on a weekend especially!  I have no methods yet in this system to allow for multiple updates but it is planned so thanks for the heads up.  I'll give this a try now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it :

```
USE [gatordata]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TriggerUserAssigned] Script Date:2/20/2016 3:42:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerUserAssigned]
ON [dbo].[User]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    INSERT  [Messages](
            [RequestID],        [AssignedToUser],   [TimeStamp],            [Hour],
            [RushService],      [Status],           [MessageText]) 
    SELECT 
            i.[Id],             i.[AssignedToUser], GETDATE(),              i.[Hour],
            i.[RushService],    i.[Status],         'New Critical Request'
    FROM    [inserted]  i
    JOIN    [deleted]   d       ON d.[Id] = i.[Id] 
    WHERE   d.[AssignedToUser] <> i.[AssignedToUser];
GO
```

By joining the inserted table to the deleted table, you should be able to compare the values in that column to determine whether it has changed. The added benefit is you can select straight from the inserted table instead of having to assign everything to variables.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck on how to mark an answer because I am sure Gordon's method works but UberDoodles worked by just copy and pasting it in.  For that reason I feel like I need to mark this as the answer.  UberDoodles you rock my friend!

Comment: I won't be offended if you'd marked Gordon's as the answer; he was first across the line :)

Comment: I did so due to your comment Uber.  I have learned from both answers and thank you both very much.